# How do you restart a app in google play store?

Tags: pokemon-go

I need to restart an app to fix a bug but i don't know how

Comment: What app? What do you mean 'restart an app in the Play Store'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of phone you have, but when I need to restart an app on my Samsung S8, I pull down the menu on the main screen and select the setting icon. Then the Apps menu, once in here I select the app I want to force restart and select it. It will bring up the option to uninstall or force stop. Force stop the app. Now that it is truely down, it should be able to restart from its normal icon.

Comment: Sometimes after pressing on the app, going to the storage label and clearing storage does it.